# Toast not working

Tags: android, maps, toast

I am using google maps but some the toast does not work. Can anyone please let me know whatd wrong with my code.

Thanks in advance

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;

import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Address;

import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPSLocatorActivity extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mapController;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

        locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            0, 
            0, 
            locationListener);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);


        // enable Street view by default
       // mapView.setStreetView(true);

        // enable to show Satellite view
         mapView.setSatellite(true);

        // enable to show Traffic on map
        // mapView.setTraffic(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(17); 
        mapView.invalidate();

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener 
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                        (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
                /*
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                         Toast.makeText(GPSLocatorActivity.this,
                        "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
                        " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        */
                //mapController.setZoom(17);               
                mapController.animateTo(point);
               mapController.setZoom(17);

             // add marker
                MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
                List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                listOfOverlays.clear();
                listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

               String address = ConvertPointToLocation(point);
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mapView.invalidate();
            }
        }

        public String ConvertPointToLocation(GeoPoint point) {   
            String address = "";
            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                    getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    point.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                    point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    for (int index = 0; index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                        address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

            return address;
        } 

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

    class MapOverlay extends Overlay
    {
        private GeoPoint pointToDraw;

        public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
            pointToDraw = point;
        }

        public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
            return pointToDraw;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return   super.onTouchEvent(e, mapView);
             //mapView.invalidate();
             //return false;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //mapView.invalidate();
            return super.onTap(p, mapView);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            // convert point to pixels
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);

            // add marker
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 24, null); // 24 is the height of image        
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: which toast? commented or the non-commented? What is the error?

Comment: This question is not clear. Please specify which among these Toasts doesn't work. And have you tried debugging to see whether the control is reaching the code for creating Toast?

Answer (score 4):

```
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(                                                                                               
                GPSLocatorActivity.this, 
                "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
                " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the beginning:

```
public class GPSLocatorActivity extends MapActivity { 
    Context mContext = this;
```

Now everytime you want to make a toast Use :

```
Toast.makeText(mContext, "some_string", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Toast.makeText(GPSLocatorActivity.this, 
                        "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
                        " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

try this...

Answer (score 0):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: It's usually recommended to include more context around the code.